Using Quadratic Formula to solve a linear equation
Yea, I know this is unnecessary, but here we go:
I was recently playing around with the quadratic formula for $ax^2+bx+c=0$, when I thought to myself, "what if I could use this to solve a linear equation?"
Clearly, this occurs when $a = 0$.
Thus, I noted the value $$x = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0}{\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}},$$
as the other value returns undefined.
This goes to $\frac{0}{0}$, so I used L'Hopital's rule, and found that the derivative of the top was $-\frac{2c}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$ while the bottom simply became $2$.
Thus, the new fraction is $$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-c}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}},$$
which is simply $\frac{-c}{b}$, the solution to $bx + c =0$.
So, yeah, in short we can solve linear equations with the quadratic formula! Don't know if this has any good use, but I found it intersting and posted it here for discussion.

For your consideration then: How would you explain the $\pm$ term?

yea, this is sort of what I'm confused with. I know when we take the positive square root of the discriminant, we get the desired solution for the line. The negative square root of the discriminant appears to go to negative infinity, which I find a bit strange. I'll leave this to the next person who sees this to come up with an explanation.

For the linear equations , we have a much simpler method to solve it. The quadratic formula is for quadratics and only for quadratics. We have to assume $a\ne 0$.

You could also use the cubic formula for solving a linear equation. But again, this would be overkill.

Is there anything more specific that you would like to know?

I’m voting to close this question because it's finished, and I have nothing more to add as the creator.

Not absurd. It's a nice exercise in singular perturbations. Actually rather deep.

I have the distinct impression of seeing this question earlier this year, but can't find it. Maybe I saw it elsewhere.

This is a common topic in older algebra texts, usually under the name "infinite roots". See the results of this 19th century google books search, for example. Essentially every one of these results is freely available, by the way.
